# I can't seems to use my python code to print with my thermal printer

Tags: python, error-handling, usb, thermal-printer

so I bought a thermal printer thinking I could use his usb port with python 3.9.7 to print with it but I get this error message:

```
c:/Users/gabpe/OneDrive/Documents/Python/Projet/Billing/TP_Test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gabpe\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Projet\Billing\TP_Test.py", line 6, in <module>
    p = Usb(0x416, 0x5011)
  File "C:\ProgramData\AnacondaML\lib\site-packages\escpos\printer.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "C:\ProgramData\AnacondaML\lib\site-packages\escpos\printer.py", line 68, in open
    self.device.detach_kernel_driver(0)
  File "C:\ProgramData\AnacondaML\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 1121, in detach_kernel_driver
    self._ctx.backend.detach_kernel_driver(
  File "C:\ProgramData\AnacondaML\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb0.py", line 662, in detach_kernel_driver
    raise NotImplementedError(self.detach_kernel_driver.__name__)
NotImplementedError: detach_kernel_driver
```

This is the code I'm using for now:

```
from escpos.printer import Usb

TPrinter = Usb(0x416, 0x5011)
TPrinter.text("Please work\n")
TPrinter.close()
```

Just a basic thing to get me started. `'0x416', '0x5011', '0x8', '0x1'` this is my printer: idVendor, idProduct, address and bus. I'm using Windows 10 and I didn't install any driver for the thermal printer, which seems to be the problem as I saw on another post, but I don't know if I can do it without or if I need and driver or something and which driver to use, or maybe if there's another library I could use. Thx

Comment: why don't you try installing a driver for your printer? is it recognized as a printer by the system?

Comment: This article may be helpful. [Every print starts with an exclamation point #470](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos/issues/470)

Comment: Hey Matthias, actually I tried to install the driver sent with the printer but it was too complicated so I was wondering if there was any better i could use.